# if/else statement with multiple conditions

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a hurdle with my if/else statement. I have a collection which sort by 2 different tags: material and size. I want an heading and paragraph to show, when neither a material or material and size is chosen. Right now, my if/else statement look likes this:

```
{% if pageValues contains 'Skummadrasser' and pageValues contains '80x200' %} 
<h2> dummy </h2> 
<p> dummy </p>

{% elsif pageValues contains 'Skummadrasser' and pageValues contains '180x200' %} 
<h2> dummy </h2> 
<p> dummy </p>

{% elsif pageValues contains 'Skummadrasser' %} 
<h2> dummy </h2>
<p> dummy </p>

{% elsif pageValues == blank %} 
<h2> dummy </h2> 
<p> dummy </p>
```

Right now, only 80x200 and blank text are printed on the collection page. If I press 180x200 tag, the headning and paragraph text to 80x200 will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Well `80x200` is present in `180x200` so when you check it with `contains` operation it will still return `true` for the first check.

You need to be more specific in your check, for example check for space with `80x200` or something else depending on your string ( if you are checking a string ).

Comment: I'm not sure how. Can you maybe give an example?